# generate-id behaviour and node-sets and variable assignment

Tags: xslt-3.0

(Saxon HE)

I'm trying to take two subsets of nodes in an XML, and then effecting apply a template to an intersection.

I'm using generate-id(), because its all i know.

So we take a trivial xml.

```
<root>
    <a oid="1" title="foo"/>        
    <a oid="1" title="bar"/>        
</root>
```

and do this, as an example, lets intersect the 'a' elements in the input document with the subset of the 1st 'a' element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output indent="true"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="foo" select="root/a[1]"/>
        <root>
            <xsl:sequence select="root/a[generate-id(.) = $foo/generate-id(.)]"/>           
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and bingo.

```
<root>
   <a oid="1" title="foo"/>     
</root>
```

ok, but my real world example is more complex, so I'll take a step closer to that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output indent="true"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="foo">
            <xsl:call-template name="getA"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="bar" select="$foo/generate-id(.)" as="xs:string"/>
        <root>
            <xsl:sequence select="root/a[generate-id(.) = $foo/generate-id(.)]"/>           
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="getA">
        <xsl:sequence select="root/a[1]"/>  
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i.e. lets construct the subset in a template using sequence to preserve the node identity (or so I thought) and:

```
<root/>
```

it breaks! so I assume that assigning the nodeset in the xsl:variable scope reconstructs the nodes somehow? and thus the ids change?

(I can of course, clone the input nodeset and label each 'a' element with a generate-id() attribute, and then use this explicit attribute to do the intersection test...and then clone the document and remove the attribute...but thats a lot of hassle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    <xsl:variable name="foo">
        <xsl:call-template name="getA"/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

to

```
    <xsl:variable name="foo" as="node()*">
        <xsl:call-template name="getA"/>
    </xsl:variable>
```

And of course there is `root/a intersect $foo` instead of that XSLT 1.0 generate-id check.

Comment: brilliant, let me try that

Comment: so if i don't do that is it generating a new set of nodes?

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd, basically, `<xsl:variable>..</xsl:variable>` without an as attribute and without a `select` attribute creates a new document (fragment) node populated with whatever the inner sequence constructor (i.e. the `..`) creates. A new document fragment node will therefore contain copies of the nodes your `xsl:sequence` selects. The gory details are in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#temporary-trees and https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#variable-values.